# How to store data from Google Ngram API?

Tags: api, text, nlp, n-gram

I need to store the data presented in the graphs on the Google Ngram website. For example, I want to store the occurences of "it's" as a percentage from 1800-2008, as presented in the following link: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%27s%3B%2Cc0.

The data I want is the data you're able to scroll over on the graph. How can I extract this for about 140 different terms (e.g. "it's", "they're", "she's", etc.)?

Comment: Google provides the full dataset here http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html - I guess extracting it from the graph / svg is not worth the effort.

Comment: i've seen that. I just don't want to download a huge part of the corpus for just this analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

econpy wrote a [nice little module in Python](https://github.com/econpy/google-ngrams/blob/master/getngrams.py) that you can use through a command-line interface.

For your "it's" example, you would need to type this command in a terminal / windows console:

```
python getngrams.py it's -startYear=1800 -endYear=2008 -corpus=eng_2009 -smoothing=3
```

This will automatically save the query result in a CSV file named after your query parameters.

Comment: I am using Anaconda Spyder (running 2.7).. How do I integrate this code into my existing code? Do I need to package it as a module and import it? I am having issues with simply copy-pasting the code into my existing code and running it..

Comment: What issues? Maybe we can fix this without going through the trouble of packaging it. I also asked econpy if he would like to make it a module. If he says no, I will take care of putting it up on PyPi so people can download it with pip.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that. I actually got it to work... I was just querying incorrectly! thanks for your help.

Comment: Even the built-in examples for this package do not work anymore.  Anyone know of an up-to-date alternative?

Comment: econpy's repo is not maintained and doesn't work anymore.  I have put a working version here https://gitlab.com/cpbl/google-ngrams and will maintain/accept further pull requests.

Comment: https://ngrams.dev provides a REST API where you can fetch this data as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

econpy's package, in @HugoMailhot's answer, no longer works (2021) and seems not maintained.
Here's a updated version, with some improvements for easier integration into Python code:
https://gitlab.com/cpbl/google-ngrams

You can call this from the command line (as in econpy's) to create a CSV file, e.g.

```
getngrams.py it's -startYear=1800 -endYear=2008 -corpus=eng_2009 -smoothing=3
```

or call it from python to get (and plot) data directly in python, e.g.:

```
from getngrams import ngrams
df = ngrams('bells and whistles -startYear=1900 -endYear=2018 -smoothing=2')
df.plot()
```

The xkcd functionality is still there too.

(Issues / bug fix pull requests /etc welcome there)